# Print Dictionary Values highest to lowest

Tags: python, dictionary

This is not a duplicate as the way the code is written makes it impossible for me to use the methods that I have researched on stack overflow.

1. I have a dictionary like so:

   ```
   class_dictionary: {'John':[2,3,4], 'Mark':[6,9,4], 'James':[0,0,0]}
   ```

   I need to print the names with the highest value for each character highest to lowest. I have already written this:

   ```
   for names, scores in class_dictionary.items():
           print("{} : {}".format(names, max(scores)))
   ```

   This prints out the highest value of each student but not in order. Like this:

   ```
   John: 4
   James: 0
   Mark: 9
   ```

   Desired Output:

   ```
   Mark: 9
   John: 4
   James: 0
   ```

   How would I print out these results highest to lowest?
2. I have a dictionary like so:

   ```
   class_dictionary: {'John':[2,3,4], 'Mark':[6,9,4], 'James':[0,0,0]}
   ```

   I need to print the names with the average value for each person highest to lowest. I have already written this:

   ```
   pprint({k: [sum(float(i) for i in v) / len(v)] for k, v in class_dictionary.items()})
   ```

   This prints out the average value of each student but not in order. Like this:

   ```
   John: 3
   Mark: 6.33333
   James: 0
   ```

   How would I print out these results highest to lowest?

   Desired Output:

   ```
   Mark: 6.33333
   John: 2
   James: 0
   ```

If you are going to vote down, please explain why so that I can improve question for next time.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to sort before you print:

```
d = {'John': [2,3,4], 'Mark': [6,9,4], 'James': [0,0,0]}

# Both of the lists below can be generators as well, just change surrounding [] to ()
# Generate a list containing names and highest scores only
highest_scores = [(name, max(scores)) for (name, scores) in d.items()]
# Generate a list containing names and averages only
averages = [(name, sum(scores)/float(len(scores))) for (name, scores) in d.items()]

# Every item is a tuple of name and score, so sort by item[1] (which is the score)
sort_key = lambda item: item[1]

for name, score in sorted(highest_scores, key=sort_key, reverse=True):
    print("%s: %d" % (name, score))

for name, avg in sorted(averages, key=sort_key, reverse=True):
    print("%s: %f" % (name, avg))
```

This prints:

```
Mark: 9
John: 4
James: 0
Mark: 6.333333
John: 3.000000
James: 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the max values in a temporary dictionary and then sort that again

```
class_dictionary= {'Jhon':[2,3,4], 'Mark':[6,9,4], 'James':[0,0,0]}

tmp = {}
for names, scores in class_dictionary.items():
     tmp[names] = max(scores)

print sorted(tmp.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda (k,v) : v )
```

You get the idea above. Give it a try with your second problem and post how far you've gone and what isn't working out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

class_dictionary =  {'Jhon':[2,3,4], 'Mark':[6,9,4], 'James':[0,0,0]}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(class_dictionary)

max_df =  test_df.max().sort_values(ascending = False)
print max_df

mean_df =  test_df.mean().sort_values(ascending = False)
print mean_df
```